# Snowflake - Time Travel Function

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a query and within that query I need to acquire data from a table called the Merchant Contract Service Discount table, however I need the data as it was at the end of the last two months. I have been attempting to use Snowflake's time travel function to acquire this, however I am getting an unexpected at error. When I run the function in a single line piece of code against the table, it works - however using it within a larger query returns this error. Any ideas on how to resolve this ?

```
DECLARE @Today                datetime = GETDATE()
DECLARE @month                int = MONTH(@today)
DECLARE @year                 int = YEAR(@today)
DECLARE @beginOfPreviousMonth datetime = DATEFROMPARTS(@year, @month - 1, 1)
DECLARE @endOfPreviousMonth   datetime = EOMONTH(@beginOfPreviousMonth)

SELECT APPLICATION_NO as AppNo,
       MID,
       m.DBA_NAME,
       s.STATUS,
       APPLICATION_APPROVED_ON as ApprovedOn,
       i.AGENCY_NO,
       i.NAME        as 'Sales Office Name',
       pm.NAME      as Pricing,
       s1.NAME       as Service,
       dgs.NAME     as Tier,
       dg.NAME,
       BASIS_POINT    as [rate(bp)],
       ITEM_FEE
FROM  PROD.DWH_REPORTING_PPS.RPT_PPS_MERCHANT m
    JOIN PROD.DWH_REPORTING_PPS.RPT_PPS_MERCHANT_CONTRACT mc
      ON m.ID = mc.MERCHANT_ID AND IS_DELETED <> 1 AND @endOfPreviousMonth BETWEEN mc.EffectiveFrom and mc.EffectiveTill
    JOIN PROD.DWH_REPORTING_PPS.RPT_PPS_MERCHANT_CONTRACT_SERVICES mcs ON mcs.CONTRACT_ID = mc.ID and mcs.IS_DELETED <> 1
    JOIN PROD.DWH_REPORTING_PPS.RPT_PPS_MERCHANT_CONTRACT_SERVICE_DISCOUNT_GROUP_SET mcsdgs
      on mcs.ID = mcsdgs.CONTRACT_SERVICE_ID and mcsdgs.IS_DELETED <> 1
    JOIN PROD.DWH_REPORTING_PPS.RPT_PPS_MERCHANT_CONTRACT_SERVICE_DISCOUNT mcsd
      ON mcsdgs.ID = mcsd.MERCHANT_CONTRACT_SERVICE_DISCOUNT_GROUP_SET_ID and mcsd.IS_DELETED <> 1
    JOIN PROD.DWH_REPORTING_PPS.RPT_PPS_STATUS s on m.STATUS_ID = s.ID
    JOIN PROD.DWH_REPORTING_PPS.RPT_PPS_PRICING_MODELS pm on pm.Id = m.PRICING_MODEL_ID
    JOIN PROD.DWH_REPORTING_PPS.RPT_PPS_DISCOUNT_GROUP dg on mcsd.DISCOUNT_GROUP_ID = dg.ID
    JOIN PROD.DWH_REPORTING_PPS.RPT_PPS_DISCOUNT_GROUP_SET dgs on dg.DISCOUNT_GROUP_SET_ID = dgs.ID
    JOIN PROD.DWH_REPORTING_PPS.RPT_PPS_SERVICE s1 on mcs.SERVICE_ID = s1.ID
    JOIN PROD.DWH_REPORTING_PPS.RPT_PPS_ISC i on i.ISC_ID = m.ISC_ID
WHERE s.STATUS NOT IN ('Entered', 'Rejected', 'Terminated', 'Cancelled', 'Pending', 'Non-Processing', 'subject-to')
    and m.HIDDEN <> 1
order by MID, dgs.SERVICE_ID, (dg.TIER_NUMBER * -1) desc`
```

Comment: Hi - what’s the error you are getting? What’s the simpler SQL query that works? What do you mean by a time travel function? The SQL you’ve given doesn’t seem to contain anything related to time travel - though it would be easier to tell if you could provide a minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

The posted `SELECT` is not using time travel. If you want to use a table in the state it was at 60 days ago, you will need to modify the `FROM` to say so with `at()`:

```sql
select * 
from my_table at(offset => -24*3600*60);
```

But this will only work if you have already change the table to retain at least 60 days of time travel data:

- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-time-travel

--

Now solving the problem in the comments:

This gives me the error `Syntax error: unexpected 'at'`:

```sql
select * 
from table1 m at(timestamp => '2023-05-11 16:50') ;
```

This fixes the problem, by moving the alias to the end:

```sql
select * 
from table1 at(timestamp => '2023-05-11 16:50') m;
```

Comment: Thanks, I should have explained further - when I add the timetravel syntax after the from statement in the query, I am getting an error - 'unexpected at' , I just wasn't sure how to resolve the error

Comment: Can you post the query that gives you errors then?

Comment: Sure, basically its the same query as above, but with the time travel syntax in the from clause as follows........ FROM  PROD.DWH_REPORTING_PPS.RPT_PPS_MERCHANT m at(TIMESTAMP => '2023-03-31 16:20:00'::timestamp) This returns an unexpected at error which I cannot resolve

Comment: Solved - check the updated answer